# .htaccess redirect doesn't seem to forward parameters properly

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to forward all traffic for `countly analytics` from a subdomain to an Amazon EC2 domain, keeping all parameters intact just as they where sent.

I am using this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^i(\?.+)$ http://ec2-11-111-11-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/i?$1 [R,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://ec2-11-111-11-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This partially works, as entering my subdomain into Safari forwards to the countly web interface, and also user sessions from my app are being recorded by countly on the AWS. However the parameters that also get sent like App Version, Screen Resolution, etc.. are not forwarded as they are just missing from the stats.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match `QUERY_STRING` using `RewriteRule` so this rule isn't really workung for you:

```
RewriteRule ^i(\?.+)$ http://ec2-11-111-11-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/i?$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

Try this code instead:

```
RewriteRule ^i/?$ http://ec2-11-111-11-11.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE,NC]
```

**`QUERY_STRING` is automatically carried over to the redirected URL.** unless `?` is used as last character in the end to strip off any existing query string.

Comment: Thanks. This still doesn't work :( Could the encoding of the params be an issue, as thinking more about this some params must be sent as it needs my api and app keys, and as the session shows up it must be sending it. Just some of them seem to be missing.

Comment: Those params are all in QUERY_STRING right? No POST data right?

Comment: Can you try: `[R,L,NC,NE]` flag in above rule?

Comment: Thank you. The NE flag has fixed it.